# Добавление новых колонок константами в запрос

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Имеется запрос, который отображает среднюю стоимость хлеба по месяцам:

```
Select month, AVG(price)
from Table
group by month
```

Результат запроса:

```
month     AVG(price)
2019-12   20
2020-01   19
2020-02   18
```

Имеется таблица констант в excel:

```
price_for_me      Месяц
15              2019-12
16              2020-01
```

В имеющийся запрос требуется добавить константы (очень важно добавить не через базу и не через подключение, а в самом запросе), чтобы результат был такой:

```
month     AVG(price)  price_for_me   
2019-12   20              15
2020-01   19              16
2020-02   18              0
```

Comment: Как-то не очень делать JOIN по месяцу. Мб в таблице есть Id продукта?

Comment: @Nick Proskuryakov, id продукта нет

Comment: Варианты: 1) любой месяц имеется в обеих таблицах 2) любой месяц может отсутствовать в любой из таблиц 3) любой месяц может отсутствовать только  в одной (какой?) из таблиц.

Comment: И укажите точно СУБД. Обязательно включая версию.

Comment: @Akina, любой месяц имеется в обеих таблицах. Clickhouse version 19.17.1

Comment: *любой месяц имеется в обеих таблицах.* Вот даже в показанном примере данных это не так - где данные за "имеющийся в таблице" месяц '2020-02', вместо которого приходится подставлять ноль?

Comment: @Akina, прошу прощения. Любой месяц может отсутствовать только во второй таблице (excel)

Comment: Ну тогда это тупо `SELECT t1.year_month, t1.avg_price, COALESCE(t2.personal_price, 0) AS personal_price FROM (запрос на получение цен) AS t1 LEFT JOIN (персональная таблица) AS t2 USING (year_month)`. Как это выглядит в синтаксисе ClickHouse - я фиг знает...

Comment: `В имеющийся запрос требуется добавить константы (очень важно добавить не через базу и не через подключение, а в самом запросе)`, а мне вот интересно а если в exelе будет миллион записей что будете делать?

Comment: @Akina, "(персональная таблица)" - это путь к excel файлу?

Answer (score -2):

добавляем в select

```
case 
when month = '2019-12' then  15 
when month = '2020-01' then 16
else 0 end as price_for_me
```